# how to configure swagger in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, swagger, spring-mybatis

I'm trying to implement swagger documentation in my project and i'm trying to configure that in my

> web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>Test</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/login</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/spring-config.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/api</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>




    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



    <error-page>
        <location>/loginError</location>
    </error-page>


</web-app>
```

but when i run the server i get the following errors:

```
Sep 08, 2017 2:50:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [Jersey2Config] in web application [/Equadis_Web_Application] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:512)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1050)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

and i'm using the following jar file

> swagger-ui-2.0.12.jar

any help please?and is there any clear example on how to do that?

> NB:i'm not using maven so i don't have a pom.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i manage to complete my task by adding the following statement in my

> spring-config.xml

```
        <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>
        <mvc:resources location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/" mapping="swagger-ui.html"></mvc:resources>
        <mvc:resources location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" mapping="/webjars/**"></mvc:resources>
        <bean class="springfox.documentation.swagger2.configuration.Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration" id="swagger2Config"/>
```

and adding the necessary jars.

Answer (score 0):

The `swagger-ui-2.0.12.jar` doesn't contain the class you need.
 `io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig` is in [`swagger-jaxrs.jar`.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-jaxrs/1.5.16)

Comment: thank you for your reply and sorry for my late reply , i've added the swagger-jaxrs.jar but sill getting the same error ,any other suggestions?

Comment: which version of swagger-jaxrs did you add? could you try using other classes from the jar to make sure the jar is added correctly?

Comment: thank you for your help , i manage to solve the problem and i will post the answer.